# How to obtain digital IIR filter coefficients for known z-plane zero-pole plot?

Tags: discrete-signals, infinite-impulse-response, poles-zeros

My clue is just to expand brackets and obtain coefficients of numerator and denominator of my transfer function. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, only if your filter structure is a *direct form*.

Comment: going from poles and zeros to Direct Form coefficients is easy.  going in the other direction is a little harder because it involves factoring polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

This might look trivial, but with the pole-zero diagram alone one can get the transfer function with a scale (gain) ambiguity.

That is, all transfer functions $(Kb,a)$, where $K$ is a constant, have the same pole-zero representation. For this reason, we usually use *pole-zero-gain* terminology.